# How to configure iOs UITextViews and UILabels so that their height is determined by their content

Tags: iphone, ios

I am basically trying to find the correct way to design a UITableViewCell that has two UITextViews and three UILabels inside it. The two UITextViews have dynamic content and their size cannot be determined until runtime.

I have tried various methods of recalculating the height of my UITextViews based on the content that is loaded in them at runtime, and though very laborious and inane, I have gotten that to work, but they then bleed over the UILabels positioned in the xib below them.

Do I really have to recalculate the y coordinates of every UILabel after calculating the new size of the UITextViews? Is there a way to simply have the elements in the xib 'push' the elements below them down based on their new size?

What is the correct approach to configuring a UITableViewCell with multiple dynamic text views so that my entire application is not comprised of code to calculate heights and coordinates?

Or is the answer that I should not be putting more than one dynamic UITextView in the same UITableViewCell ?

Answer (score 2):

I have used something like this for a cell to calculate its height in

```
tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

function

```
    CGSize labelSize = [self.comments sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:17.0] 
                                                 constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT) 
                                                     lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return labelSize.height + 20;
```

+20 is for padding.

and also if you are having every cell like the one you mention above, than you can create a class of UITableViewCell with following UIView elements inside it.

Answer (score 1):

iOS doesn't seem to have any sort of flow layout engine -- at least none that I can think of.
If, however, your labels are located at the bottom of your UITableViewCell, you might be able to get away with setting the UILabel's autoresizingMask mask property to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin so that the UILabels will anchor itself at the bottom. This is assuming that you already adjusted the size of the UITableViewCell to fit the entire controls. Otherwise, I think the best way to handle this is to recalculate the y coordinates of the labels.

Answer (score 0):

I found it useful to add this sort of behavior as a category on UIView so a view can resize one of its subviews to fit some arbitrary text, and optionally resize the parent view to fit the newly enlarged subview as needed.

http://blog.carbonfive.com/2009/07/10/resizing-uilabel-to-fit-text/

Comment: Thanks for this. How have you delt with the issue that then develops where resized labels will bleed over the labels below them? Is it then necessary to recalculate the y coordinate of every label in the same view?

Comment: If you only resize a single subview then that shouldn't be a problem as you can use springs to position the resizable view relative to the top of its parent view, position all other subviews relative to the bottom, and resize the parent view as the lable/text field grows. When that's not possible then yes, you need to re-layout your subviews after resizing them. Possibly just by calling `-layoutSubviews` but it depends on how you build and manage your views and if you are animating this change.